# Is there a VIM plugin available to add JSONPath / jq / JMESPath path searching?

Tags: filetype-json

I have a large JSON file that I am largely familiar with, but I have to jump around the file in VIM quite a bit and tweak options and such.

I was wondering if there is a VIM plugin available that allows me to specify a JSONPath / jq / JMESPath path on the search command line to easily jump to a specific key/value object in the file?

I found a comparable plugin for xpath in XML files: https://github.com/actionshrimp/vim-xpath , but the JSON-based plugins I have found only deal with syntax highlighting, linting, pretty-printing/formatting, etc.

Ideally, I'd like to just be able to use JSON Path notation (or the like) to easily jump to the spot in my JSON file I need to read/modify/etc.

Comment: [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45024316/7796750) uses the `input_line_number` filter of `jq`, but this seems to provide the matching line numbers only for multiple single line JSON strings input. Are you working on a single indented JSON file? If you can output the line of the intended match with any of these tools, getting Vim's cursor to jump at it is trivial. I don't know about xpath capabilities but live evaluation might require a more consequent script.

Comment: Yes, usually, the JSON files I am working on are two or four spaced indented pretty-printed JSON files. Thanks for the SO answer. That's an interesting point, if it worked. Unfortunately, I am experiencing the same issue as https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1193 where the output is the total number of lines and not the line that the filter occurs at.

Answer (score 3):

I recently wrote a plugin for this called [vim-jsonpath](https://github.com/mogelbrod/vim-jsonpath). It currently provides the following (mappable) commands:

- `:JsonPath`: Echoes the path to the identifier under the cursor.
- `:JsonPath path.to.prop`: Searches the active buffer for the given path, placing the cursor on it if found.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can use something like [gron](https://github.com/tomnomnom/gron/) or [jsonpipe](https://github.com/zacharyvoase/jsonpipe) to create paths next to the content.

An example of what `gron` output would look like:

```
json[0].commit.author = {};
json[0].commit.author.date = "2016-07-02T10:51:21Z";
json[0].commit.author.email = "mail@tomnomnom.com";
json[0].commit.author.name = "Tom Hudson";
```

You can do your searching and editing then undo this via `%!gron --ungron`.

Comment: Thanks! I just discovered `gron` yesterday. The only thing is, it doesn't output the line numbers of where each object lives, which would inform VIM of which line to jump to. I'm opening an issue on `gron` here: https://github.com/tomnomnom/gron/issues/33

Comment: The author of `gron` got back to me. He indicated that the Go JSON library doesn't provide this information, and that in order to do so, he'd have to write a custom JSON parser (which he is unwilling to do at this point). So back to the drawing board (unless you have another idea of how the `gron` solution would still work without specifying the line numbers.

Comment: Honestly, I gave `gron` as an alternative, because you can find the component you want, modify it, and then `grun --ungron` your text back to json. I do not know of a json path finding tool. If you find one please answer your own question

Comment: I’ve been using gron for git diffs of json, but this is brilliant. I hate the way JSON works in an edit buffer (if I’m just viewing/slicing it I tend to go for :JqPlay from some plugin)